# how to automate docker development environment startup for a multi-service web app (on Linux)

Tags: linux, bash, docker, automation, development-environment

I currently have to do the following 9+ steps just to launch my dev stack using Docker on Ubuntu 16.04 before I can start writing code:

- open a terminal and cd into service #1's source code directory
- docker-compose up service #1 (Python/Django, Redis, and Postgres containers)
- docker exec service1 bash; start Django dev server for debugging
- repeat for service #2, using terminal tabs to keep things organized
- open a terminal and cd into the front-end Angular app source directory
- run a webpack dev server with npm
- open one or more terminals and cd into the appropriate source code directories to edit

I tried writing a shell script to launch everything with `gnome-terminal --tab -e "bash -c docker-compose up"`, etc, but this gets awkward and will fail when trying to then shell into containers and run things, e.g. `gnome-terminal --tab -e "bash -c \"docker-compose exec service1 bash -c rundev.sh \""`.  I also tried using `xdotool`, but it can't identify the docker shell terminal tabs for some reason.

Running a SPA with two back-end services and doing local development on each of the three code-bases doesn't seem like a bizarre use-case for Docker app development to me.

Does anyone have any suggestions of tools or an alternative dev environment setup for simplifying things?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a bash script, but the proper way would be docker-compose. You need to create 2x services with their respective commands to run. Here is an [example](https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/) for rails app. Your docker-compose.yml should be something similar to this.

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Comment: So that only starts a single service with docker-compose and running a dev server through docker compose prevents access to interactive debugging.  That's why I start up the containers with docker compose, then shell into them to start a dev server so I can access my debugger in the container.